# Use tf.exe to create a new label from an existing label

Tags: powershell, tfs

In Visual Studio it is possible to create a new source control label from the files associated with an existing label.

How would I do that in a Powershell script, using `tf.exe` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the `/version` parameter on the `tf.exe label` command.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/56f7w6be%28v%3Dvs.80%29) explains that the `/version` parameter should be formatted as L followed by the label name:

```
# Create an alias to tf.exe
Set-Alias tf "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe"

$labelName = "New label"
$labelComment = "Comment on new label"
$previousLabelName = "Nightly Build"
$sourceFolder = "C:\Folder\Containing Source\"

tf label $labelName $sourceFolder /comment:$labelComment /version:L$previousLabelName /recursive /child:Replace
```